# how to compile Cuda source with Go language's cgo?

Tags: go, cuda, environment, nvcc, cgo

I wrote a simple program in cuda-c and it works on eclipse nsight. This is source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


__global__ void add( int a,int b, int *c){
*c = a + b;
}

int main(void){

int c;
int *dev_c;

cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, sizeof(int));

add <<<1,1>>>(2,7,dev_c);

cudaMemcpy(&c, dev_c, sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

printf("\n2+7= %d\n",c);
cudaFree(dev_c);

return 0;
}
```

Now I'm trying to use this code with Go language with cgo!!!
So I wrote this new code:

```
package main

//#include "/usr/local/cuda-7.0/include/cuda.h"
//#include "/usr/local/cuda-7.0/include/cuda_runtime.h"
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -lcuda
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -lcurand
////default location:
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64 -L/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib
//#cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/local/cuda-7.0/include/
//
//
//
//
//
//
//
//
//
//
/*

#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void add( int a,int b, int *c){
    *c = a + b;
}

int esegui_somma(void){

    int c;
    int *dev_c;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, sizeof(int));
    add <<<1,1>>> (2,7,dev_c);
    cudaMemcpy(&c, dev_c, sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(dev_c);
    return c;
}
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main(){
    fmt.Printf("il risultato è %d",C.esegui_somma)
}
```

But it doesn't work!!
I read this error message:

```
cgo_cudabyexample_1/main.go:34:8: error: expected expression before '<' token
add <<<1,1>>> (2,7,dev_c);
      ^
```

I think that I must to set nvcc cuda compiler for cgo instead of gcc.
How can I do it? Can I change CC environment variable?
best regards

Comment: Have you tried just using the standard CC anc CXX environment variables? (I have no idea if cgo works with cuda in this case, but it should be easy to try)

Comment: Hi, thank you for response.
In /etc/profile file i added this:

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin  
export CC=nvcc  


now this is errore message:

             nvcc fatal : Unknown option 'dM'

Comment: I wasn't sure how cuda compiler worked, but it's obviously not a standard CC replacement. I think you'll need to compile the cuda code outside of the Go program. (as an aside, you don't need to edit the global profile to set an environment variable, you don't even need to export it if you define it with the command).

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out how to do this. Thing biggest problem is that `nvcc`does not follow `gcc` standard flags and unlike `clang` it won't silently ignore them. `cgo` triggers the problem by adding a bunch of flags not explicitly specified by the user.

To make it all work, you'll need to separate out your device code and the functions that directly call it into separate files and compile/package them directly using `nvcc` into a shared library (.so). Then you'll use cgo to link this shared library using whatever default linker you have on your system. The only thing you'll have to add is `-lcudart` to your `LDFLAGS` (linker flags) to link the CUDA runtime.